# Eclipse isn't using allotted heap; I get an out of memory error?

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am using Eclipse (newly installed) to run some Java code, and for some reason I get an outOfMemoryError: Java heap space, however I set the -Xms and -Xmx to 1gb each and when I run the code, the little bar on the bottom never goes past 70 mb -_-. Can someone help me here? Thanks.

Comment: Is this helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410277/getting-out-of-memory-java-heap-space-but-while-viewing-heap-space-it-max-uses

Comment: "however I set the -Xms and -Xmx to 1gb each". How have you set this? And when are you getting the OOME? FYI, Eclipse launches new JVMs if you are running Java applications from within.

Comment: I thought the -Xms and -Xmx were set in eclipse by going into my prefs file (eclipse.ini) and adding those in. I get the error when my code is running

Comment: no set it in the debug or run configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the OOME when running your code (as a Java application, or within a Java application server). This JVM is different from the JVM used by Eclipse, and will have it's own Xms and Xmx values.

If you need to modify the settings for the launched process, you'll need to [modify the runtime configuration of the project](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-executionArgs.htm) to specify the arguments to the JVM explicitly. The default values in use may be insufficient for your application.

Comment: thanks a lot Vineet. Is there any way to make these arguments the default for all programs?

Comment: @Descartes, I'm afraid no such mechanism exists to my knowledge. At the very best, you may edit the .launch files directly. They're usually located in your workspace in the  `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` directory.